# Convert Parquet to CSV

Tags: python, csv, command-line, parquet

How to convert Parquet to CSV from a local file system (e.g. python, some library etc.) but WITHOUT Spark? (trying to find as simple and minimalistic solution as possible because need to automate everything and not much resources).

I tried with e.g. `parquet-tools` on my Mac but data output did not look correct.

Need to make output so that when data is not present in some columns - CSV will have corresponding NULL (empty column between 2 commas)..

Thanks.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can do this by using the Python packages `pandas` and `pyarrow` (`pyarrow` is an optional dependency of `pandas` that you need for this feature).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_parquet('filename.parquet')
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

When you need to make modifications to the contents in the file, you can standard `pandas` operations on `df`.

Comment: How did you install pyarrow? Tried e.g. `pip3.7 install --no-cache pyarrow` and getting error at the end `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/xy/b__x_l9n1kl9_llyngq1cvddqsd9bn/T/pip-install-3p7vvogb/pyarrow/`

Comment: Start using Anaconda and virtual env in it and this problem went away..

Comment: `pyarrow` is not yet available as a Python 3.7 wheel. We will soon release a 0.10 release (1-2 weeks) that will also provide 3.7 builds.

Comment: @UweL.Korn this fails for me. Script finishes with exit code -1. This only happens on Centos7 with Python 3.6 and Python 3.7. Have got pandas==0.25.0, any suggestions?

Comment: @Rob any error message or context around the problem?

Comment: Nope, nothing at all. Whole output is as follows: 

```ssh://centos@10.1.11.111:22/usr/local/bin/python3.7 -u /home/centos/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 0.0.0.0 --port 35809 --file /tmp/pycharm_project_909/test_some.py
pydev debugger: process 31141 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 191.7479.30)

Process finished with exit code -1```

Comment: Can you run the code directly without using PyCharm as a remote debugger around it?

Comment: Have switched over to fastparquet engine. Have failures on the same files but with an error message relating to a compression type: Decompression 'SNAPPY' not available.  Options: ['GZIP', 'UNCOMPRESSED']

Comment: To avoid saving without the index in the csv file, do ```df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)```

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few options depending on what technology you like to use

**DuckDB (Python + other languages)**

jcarcamoh DuckDB query will import csv and output parquet.

Here is a DuckDB query that will read a parquet file and output a csv file

`duckb.sql("COPY(SELECT * FROM 'path/to/file.parquet' TO 'path/to/file.csv' (HEADER, FORMAT 'csv'))")`

Just replace the path/to/file parts with the paths to your input file and where you want the output written. DuckDB Copy function [docs](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/statements/copy.html)

The HEADER parameter will output a header row into your CSV. Remove it if you don't want a header row.

DuckDB also has clients for [other languages](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/overview)

**Pandas (Python)**

Expanding on what Uwe L. Korn said - if you have a large parquet file and it is loading slowly into Pandas then try using the fastparquet engine of Pandas [read_parquet method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html#pandas-read-parquet).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_parquet('filename.parquet', engine='fastparquet')
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

I have found the fastparquet engine to speed up reading parquet quite a lot, YMMV.

**Using an online tool**

Sometimes it is difficult to debug Parquet issues because the files can't be opened in a text editor. Online tools like [this](https://www.parquetdata.com/convert/parquet/csv) can be useful during development to see whether the outputs look correct.

Comment: two small typos in the duckdb package name (`duckb`->`duckdb`, parenthesis had to be closed before `TO`):

`duckdb.sql("COPY(SELECT * FROM 'path/to/file.parquet') TO 'path/to/file.csv' (HEADER, FORMAT 'csv')")`

Comment: Also, note that you can run the duckdb CLI instead of using Python:

`./duckdb -c "COPY(SELECT * FROM 'path/to/file.parquet') TO 'path/to/file.csv' (HEADER, FORMAT 'csv')"`

Answer (score 2):

There is the package [fastparquet](https://pypi.org/project/fastparquet/) to read data from parquet files:

```py
from fastparquet import ParquetFile

# Reading the data from Parquet File
pf = ParquetFile("userdata.parquet")

# Converting data in to pandas dataFrame
dataFrame = pf.to_pandas()

# Converting to CSV
dataFrame.to_csv("converted.csv", index = False)
```

Comment: made the changes :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Jupyter noteboooks, you could use:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
!{sys.executable} -m pip install pyarrow
parquet_file = 'fhv_tripdata_2022-04.parquet'
df = pd.read_parquet(parquet_file)
csv_output = 'yellow_taxi_cab.csv'
df.to_csv(csv_output, index=False, sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use duckdb to achieve this:

```
duckdb.sql("COPY(SELECT * FROM path/to/file.csv TO 'path/to/file.parquet' (FORMAT 'parquet'))")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you elaborate?