# How to convert hadoop avro, parquet, as well as text file to csv without spark

Tags: scala

I have hdfs versions of avro, parquet, and text file. Unfortunately, I can't use spark to convert them to csv. I saw from an earlier so question that this doesn't seem to be possible. [How to convert HDFS file to csv or tsv.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54034376/how-to-convert-hdfs-file-to-csv-or-tsv)
Is this possible, and if so, how do I do this?

Comment: please respond with an actual answer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51215166/convert-parquet-to-csv for parquet to csv.

Comment: Unfortunately, my codebase doesn't have python. There are no scala questions out there with this topic.

Comment: then you have a problem

Comment: Good for you. I am not sure I understand the issues but SO to the rescue

Comment: Thanks man. I'm not sure I understand the solution either, but it seems like it will work.

Comment: Good question is 5

Comment: Thanks for the upvote man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://www.programcreek.com/scala/org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader) will help you to read Avro files (just avoid schema evolution/modifications...).
[Example](https://www.programcreek.com/scala/org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader).

As to Parquet, you can use [parquet-mr](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/pom.xml), take a look at ParquetReader.
[Example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader): ignore the Spark usage, they just use it in order to create a Parquet file to be used later on with ParquetReader.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the help. Quick question. Does this handle all the edge cases? Ie null values.

Comment: I think it does, test it. One crucial thing you should take under consideration is that it does not support scheme evolution. All files should have the same schema when read.

Comment: Could you also clarify, why we need both serialize and deserealize. I thought we would just read the avro using the filereader, and then write to csv no?

Comment: You don't need both. They just give an example of read and write. Use whatever you need accordingly