# Taking Multiple Parquet Files and converting them to CSV Outputs

Tags: python, csv, parquet, file-conversion

New to Python here

I have a folder with multiple parquet files as shown below (there are close to twenty). I would like to convert all of them to separate csv files published on my desktop. Any guidance on a standard code I could leverage to do this? Assume that the structure within them are all the same.

Thanks so much.

```
File1.parquet
File2.parquet
File3.parquet
```

to

```
File1.csv
File2.csv
File3.csv
```

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51215166/convert-parquet-to-csv

Comment: It helps for one file - i have many files and trying to do it in one go.

Comment: you can call it on each file using loop

Comment: can you post an example template?

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
from fastparquet import ParquetFile

path = '.'  
prqtfiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.parquet")
for p in prqtfiles:
 pr = ParquetFile(p, sep='\t')
 df = pr.to_pandas()
 df.to_csv(p[:-8] + '.csv', index=False)
```