# Convert multiple parquet files to individual csv's

Tags: pandas, csv, parquet

I am trying to convert multiple parquet files to individual csv's. I have tried this code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69051154/taking-multiple-parquet-files-and-converting-them-to-csv-outputs) but when i run it, it only converts around 10 of the files.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
from fastparquet import ParquetFile

path = '.'
prqtfiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.parquet")
for p in prqtfiles:
 pr = ParquetFile(p, sep='\t')
 df = pr.to_pandas()
 df.to_csv(p[:-8] + '.csv', index=False)
```

Any idea why its doing this?
Thanks,
David

Comment: This code works. Your problem is likely something external and specific to you machine/parquet files that is not related to this code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So I'm new to python and I got that code from another site. While your response confirms the code is correct, I wouldn't have a clue what to check on my PC\file. Would you have a different (and hopefully simple) method of achieving my required result?

Comment: Without your actual parquet files, I have no idea about what's going on from your side. Something you can try is to run your code in debug mode, add a breakpoint inside the loop, and then follow the code step by step to see why it stops at 10. You could also add `print` statements inside the for loop so that you see something printed with every run of the code.  Then you can figure out why the code breaks out at file number 10. Maybe there is an error?